# Human femur maximum strength

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, bio-mechanics

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=os98s9kBlOI it is demonstrated that a moose leg bone can support until nearly 10 tonne before break. Is there any similar demonstration on human femurs? How much weight a human femur can support vertically before it is crushed?

Comment: that's not a whole bone just a section, there are similar test of other cortical bone. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128038024000111

Comment: It just uses a tiny cube (5mm x 5mm x 5mm) of cortical bone from a femur. Is there any tests that used whole human femurs?

Comment: I doubt it, there is not much scientific value to such an act and getting human bone for testing is not easy.

Comment: Do you think the midshaft section look stronger than it looks because of its structure (which is shorter with both ends flattened)? I think if it is a whole leg bone, it will break much faster.

Comment: That video isn't a scientific test, bone has aligned strength, putting a full femur with curves and rounded ends in a press with flat surfaces doesn't tell you anything useful. Bone is not subjected to force in that way in a living creature, that is why scientific test use small segments.

Comment: So that being said, a midshaft section with flattened ends look stronger (can support more load) than it seems because it is more stable compare to a whole leg bone. Isn't it?